# Can't find Color Balance node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, color

I'm using Blender 2.78 on a Mac and I can't find the color balance node in cycles, do I need to install an add on or enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The color balance node only exists in the Compositor window, not in the Shader Editor.

[image]

To go to the compositor, press this icon at the bottom of the node panel editor and check *Use Nodes*

**In Blender 2.8x and further:**
[image: Workspace toolbar in 2.8]

**In versions 2.7x or earlier:** select the compositing option.

[image: Old workspace selector]

and select use nodes:
[image]